# If I have a class that extends JPanel, should I define buttons in constructor or add() them?

Tags: java, swing

So I wanted to know if it's wrong to do one of the following:

If I have a class `MyJPanel extends JPanel`, should I either...

a)

Write the constructor so that it adds JComponents during construction of the panel itself like this:

```
public MyJPanel() {

    JButton button = new JButton("Hello");
    JLabel labelOne = new JLabel("Hello");
    JLabel labelTwo = new JLabel("Bye");

    add(button);
    add(labelOne);
    add(labelTwo);

}
```

or b)

Declare these components in the class that calls `MyJPanel testPanel = new MyJPanel();` and explicitly `add()` them? So basically:

```
public class SomeOtherClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JButton button = new JButton("Hello");
        JLabel labelOne = new JLabel("Hello");
        JLabel labelTwo = new JLabel("Bye");

        MyJPanel testPanel = new MyJPanel();
        testPanel.add(button);
        testPanel.add(labelOne);
        testPanel.add(labelTwo);

    }

}
```

I know this may be a stupid question, but I just wanted to know if both are okay to do or if one of them isn't.

Comment: If you add them from another class, what is then so special about your panel that you still need to extend `JPanel`

Comment: Well I could setLayout() and a couple other things within the constructor and then call add() from the outside for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this class a "component", that has some specific features (the buttons). That's why I think it doesn't make sense to add the features from the outside. To add the buttons in the constructor has a couple of advantages:

- Reusability - you can reuse the component in other places / applications etc.
- Encapsulation - the component doesn't rely on any external dependencies; this improves also testability.
- Maintainability - you can easily refactor your code, by just moving this class around - no worries about any code outside of this class.

Comment: Alright, I thought so too. I just thought that it may have been possible that explicitly adding components to the JPanel would make more sense in terms of readability... I just needed some reassurance though, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The code which you presented is just a test code, so it is hard to say how it should be designed. None of those way you presented is wrong on principle. As the rule for the real world appications you should make highly maintainable, reusable components. However the answer how you can create them depends on which level of flexibility you need. You can consider also using some factory methods which produces component in exaclty that shape you need. It is also not a bad idea to take a look how some 'default' java components are designed and implemented for example take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html.